# How to programatically get the binding expression from a DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Given a datagrid with a DataGridCheckBoxColumn bound to a boolean object

```
<datagrid .....>
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Issues"  Binding="{Binding HasIssue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

How can I programmatically obtain the Binding Expression to be able to call UpdateTarget() ?

ie.

```
   var expression = datagrid1.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.**WhatProperty**);
    if (expression != null)
       expression .UpdateTarget();
```

I have also tried

```
var expression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(datagrid1, ***`WhatDependencyObjectHere`***);
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting the binding expression? (in the code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your exact question, you would have to get the actual `CheckBox` that the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` is generating. Here's an example function. I don't know what type of collection your `ItemsSource` is, so I called mine `TestObject` and set `ItemsSource` to an `IList<TestObject>`.

```
static void UpdateBindingTarget(DataGrid dg, DataGridCheckBoxColumn col, TestObject item)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)col.GetCellContent(row);
    var be = cb.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
    if (be != null) { be.UpdateTarget(); }
}
```

**The real question is *why* you would want to do this in the first place.** The above is not what I would consider good practice, more of a hacky workaround. If you need your binding source to update the target, it should either inherit `DependencyObject` and use a `DependencyProperty`, or implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event.